# Search in list of tkinter widgets

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have some tkinter widgets stored in a list. I'd like to search for an object in that list, by I don't know the syntax.

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()
base = tk.Frame(main).pack()

l = []

for i in range(3):
    et = tk.Label(base, text='label '+str(i))
    et.pack()
    l.append(et)

print(base.Label.!label in l)

main.mainloop()
```

**Note.**
Certainly this is a minimal example to understand where my mistake is.
The gui actually consists of an n x m matrix of tkinker entries, whose cells, rows, and columns should be dynamically added, deleted, modified, and even inserted or switched.

To do this, I have a dictionary that associates index tuples (i,j) with tkinter entries. When an entry is chosen with the mouse, that object is known, but what I really need to know is its index (i,j) to manage all the rest of the information (maths operations over arrays, etc).

[image]

Comment: This seems a bit complicated for this task. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @e_moro Do you want the `n`th label? If so, use `n_th_label = l[n]`.

Comment: why do you want to do it ? Python uses objects instead IDs like `base.Label.!label`. Maybe first check `print( et )` and `print( dir(et) )` to see what you get. And as I remeber `tkinter` should have function which gets ID like `base.Label.!label` and gives you object

Comment: @furas You are thinking of [`.nametowidget(...)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.nametowidget-method). But you never have to use it, because each time you see it, it's always attached to a widget

Comment: @TheLizzard you are right. I had to use this only one or two times and I didn't remeber  name :) And I agree that it would be better to use other method to work with widgets (which are objects in Python)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could use the index of separate list and use `widget.grid_info()` to retrieve the indices.

```
top_bar     = []
sidebar     = []
```

The rendering and the content have separated masters to achieve that the indexes of the lists, which starts with 0, match with the column and row of your *inner* grid.
The outer master could be populated like this, important to note is that Label on grid position 0,0 is not append to any of the lists but is gridded to fill the space. The grid_configure is just a optical improvement.

```
def outer_matrix():
    for x in range(COLUMNS+1):
        for y in range(ROWS+1):
            ref = tk.Label(root,)#justify='center')
            txt = None
            if x == 0 and y != 0:
                txt = y
                top_bar.append(ref)
            elif y == 0 and x != 0:
                txt = x
                sidebar.append(ref)
            if txt != None or x == 0 and y == 0:
                ref.config(text = txt, width=10)
                ref.grid(row = y, column = x, sticky='nswe')
                root.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)
                root.grid_rowconfigure(y,weight=1)
```

Full Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

ROWS = 6
COLUMNS = 6

top_bar     = []
sidebar     = []

def outer_matrix():
    for x in range(COLUMNS+1):
        for y in range(ROWS+1):
            ref = tk.Label(root,)#justify='center')
            txt = None
            if x == 0 and y != 0:
                txt = y
                top_bar.append(ref)
            elif y == 0 and x != 0:
                txt = x
                sidebar.append(ref)
            if txt != None or x == 0 and y == 0:
                ref.config(text = txt, width=10)
                ref.grid(row = y, column = x, sticky='nswe')
                root.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)
                root.grid_rowconfigure(y,weight=1)
            else:
                ref.destroy()
                

def inner_matrix():
    for x in range(COLUMNS):
        for y in range(ROWS):
            ref = tk.Entry(inner_frame, width=10)
            ref.grid(column=x,row=y, sticky='nswe')
            inner_frame.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)
            inner_frame.grid_rowconfigure(y,weight=1)
            ref.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e:highlight(e))
            ref.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e:highlight(e))


def highlight(event):
    info = event.widget.grid_info()
    x_info = info['row']
    y_info = info['column']
    if 'FocusIn' in str(event):
        top_bar[x_info].configure(bg='yellow')
        sidebar[y_info].configure(bg='yellow')
    if 'FocusOut' in str(event):
        top_bar[x_info].configure(bg='SystemButtonFace')
        sidebar[y_info].configure(bg='SystemButtonFace')
    
    


root = tk.Tk()
root.update()
inner_frame = tk.Frame(root,bg='red')
inner_frame.grid(row=1,column=1,
                 columnspan=COLUMNS,
                 rowspan = ROWS,
                 sticky = 'nswe')

outer_matrix()
inner_matrix()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Btw it will be a bit faster if you used `root.grid_columnconfigure(tuple(range(COLUMNS+1)), weight=1)` outside of the loop.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks for the tip. I will implement it in my personal `.py` but will leave the answer as is. Because I think this might not be intuitive for other readers, especially beginners.